WooCommerce 3rd product image alt attribute not being set to product title
I'm trying to update all product images alt attributes to product title with this code:
// set product img alt and title to product title
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'change_attachement_image_attributes', 20, 2);

function change_attachement_image_attributes( $attr, $attachment ){
    // Get post parent
    $parent = get_post_field( 'post_parent', $attachment);

    // Get post type to check if it's product
    $type = get_post_field( 'post_type', $parent);
    if( $type != 'product' ){
        return $attr;
    }

    if ( isset( $attr['class'] ) && 'custom-logo' === $attr['class'] ) {
        return $attr;
    }

    /// Get title
    $title = get_post_field( 'post_title', $parent);

    $attr['alt'] = $title;
    $attr['title'] = $title;

    return $attr;
}

The code pasted above does change product images alt attribute to product title except 3rd image in product gallery. The 3rd image at every product gets alt set to title of "Girls sweatshirt pink" product. How can I overcome this problem?

@LoicTheAztec I deleted ss.

The solution to this problem was to rename affected images by adding number at the end of file name and swap existing one with renamed.
